# Overflow: scroll doesn't work properly with flex: 1

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, overflow

I am building frontend in html/sass/js for my web api written in .net core web api.
I met small problem with which I am struggling for few hours and I dont have any ideas how can i solve this.

Getting to the point I want to build sidenav where informations going to be added dynamically using JS. Simplifying it's look like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container-search">
        <header class="header">
          [...not important code...]
        </header>
        <div class="content search-content">
          <nav class="sidenav">
            <h3 class="sidenav__text"></h3>
            <form action="#" class="sidenav__searchbar">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="sidenav__searchbar__input"
                placeholder=""
              />
              <button class="sidenav__searchbar__btn button"></button>
            </form>
            <h4 class="sidenav__ingredients"></h4>
            <ul class="sidenav__products-list">
              <li class="product">
                <div class="product__info">
                  <h5 class="product__info-name"></h5>
                  <h6 class="product__info-type"></h6>
                </div>
                <div class="product__action">X</div>
              </li>           
            </ul>
            <div class="sidenav__btns">
              <button class="sidenav__btn button">Wyczyść</button>
              <button class="sidenav__btn button">Filtruj</button>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <main class="search"></main>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-results"></div>
      <!-- <footer class="footer"></footer> -->
    </div>
  </body>
```

I specified height of .container-search like this:

```
.container-search {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 92vh;
  margin: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-light-1);
}
```

Then my .search-content look like this:

```
.search-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Now my .sidenav__products-list height is defined by property flex: 1, because I want it to take up all the free space

```
.sidenav {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  min-width: 30rem;
 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```
sidenav__products-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
```

Now when I am adding more `<li class="product">` there is no showing overflow. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

I don't want to specify max-height property, because I want to my .sidenav__products-list height automatically adjust to screen height, this is why I use flex: 1 on this class

For more information this is my github -> https://github.com/szymonJag/CookLib/tree/main/CookLib/wwwroot

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `flex:1` to your `.sidenav__products-list` Element and the rest, to your `.sidenav` Element.
Try This:

```css
.sidenav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: auto;
  height:100vh;
  }
.sidenav__products-list{
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sidenav">
  <h3 class="sidenav__text">Co masz w lodówce?
  </h3>
  <form action="#" class="sidenav__searchbar">
    <input
           type="text"
           class="sidenav__searchbar__input"
           placeholder="Give ingredients..."
           />
    <button class="sidenav__searchbar__btn button">Search</button>
  </form>
  <h4 class="sidenav__ingredients">Ingredients list:
  </h4>
  <ul class="sidenav__products-list">
    <li class="product">
      <div class="product__info">
        <h5 class="product__info-name">Onion</h5>
        <h6 class="product__info-type">Vegetables
        </h6>
      </div>
      <div class="product__action">X
      </div>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
  <div class="sidenav__btns">
    <button class="sidenav__btn button">Clear
    </button>
    <button class="sidenav__btn button">Filter
    </button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To give wider context I edited post. I doesnt't define height in sidenav. Your answer works, but in my case it's not responsive so i would have to create media queries.

Comment: In this case, you need to add 'over-flow:hidden;' to your ".search-content" element

Comment: and if you dont want to hide the over-flow of your intier .search-content, your .sidenav must have a fixed size and then you can hide its over-flow.

Comment: I thought I already answered you yesterday but nvm... Your answer fixed my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sidenav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: hidden;
      height: fit-content;
  }
.sidenav__products-list{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sidenav">
  <h3 class="sidenav__text">Co masz w lodówce?
  </h3>
  <form action="#" class="sidenav__searchbar">
    <input
           type="text"
           class="sidenav__searchbar__input"
           placeholder="Give ingredients..."
           />
    <button class="sidenav__searchbar__btn button">Search</button>
  </form>
  <h4 class="sidenav__ingredients">Ingredients list:
  </h4>
  <ul class="sidenav__products-list">
    <li class="product">
      <div class="product__info">
        <h5 class="product__info-name">Onion</h5>
        <h6 class="product__info-type">Vegetables
        </h6>
      </div>
      <div class="product__action">X
      </div>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
  <div class="sidenav__btns">
    <button class="sidenav__btn button">Clear
    </button>
    <button class="sidenav__btn button">Filter
    </button>
  </div>
</nav>
```